# double nested elasticsearch query does not work for term clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run ES query on double nested document. Term query inside the nested query does not seem to work. If i replace the below term query with terms query it works. I am posting both mapping and query for your reference. Am i doing anything wrong? I am using ES version 6.4. Basically i want to an AND condition on the "bio.mut.type" field and return the docs accordingly.

Mapping:

```
{
    "assoc": {
        "date_detection": true,
        "properties": {
            "bio": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                                                "node": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "index": "true"
                    },
                    "mut": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "biomarkerType": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "createdBy": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "creationDate": {
                                "type": "date"
                            },
                            "domain": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "node": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "status": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "type": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "updateDate": {
                                "type": "date"
                            },
                            "updatedBy": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "version": {
            "type": "keyword"

        },
                "domain": {
            "type": "keyword"

        }
    }
}
```

QUERY:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "nested" : {
          "query" : {
            "terms" : {
              "bio.node" : [
                "X"
              ],
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          },
          "path" : "bio",
          "ignore_unmapped" : false,
          "score_mode" : "none",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "nested" : {
          "query" : {
            "nested" : {
              "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                  "must" : [
                    {
                      "term" : {
                        "bio.mut.type" : {
                          "value" : "M",
                          "boost" : 1.0
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term" : {
                        "bio.mut.type" : {
                          "value" : "F",
                          "boost" : 1.0
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term" : {
                        "bio.mut.type" : {
                          "value" : "C",
                          "boost" : 1.0
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              },
              "path" : "bio.mut",
              "ignore_unmapped" : false,
              "score_mode" : "none",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          },
          "path" : "bio",
          "ignore_unmapped" : false,
          "score_mode" : "none",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "terms" : {
          "domain" : [
            "X"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "must_not" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "status" : [
            "Deleted"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_index": "XXX",
    "_type": "XXX",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "bio": [{
            "mut": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "type": "M"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "type": "F"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "type": "C"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: By having 3 `term` queries in a bool/must you're basically trying to retrieve documents which have all three values (M, F and C) in the `bio.mut.type` field **in the same nested document**, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Val you are absolutely right. I want to retrieve all three values (M, F and C) in the bio.mut.type field in the same nested document. Like an AND clause.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you expect to match?

Comment: @val i have updated the question with sample doc. ignore any typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you're trying to match separate nested documents, i.e. return the top-level document that contains different nested documents that all match the nested queries.

Replace the second top-level `must` element by the following one:

```
    {
      "nested": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "bio.mut.type": {
                        "value": "M",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "bio.mut",
                  "ignore_unmapped": false,
                  "score_mode": "none",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "bio.mut.type": {
                        "value": "F",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "bio.mut",
                  "ignore_unmapped": false,
                  "score_mode": "none",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "bio.mut.type": {
                        "value": "C",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "bio.mut",
                  "ignore_unmapped": false,
                  "score_mode": "none",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "path": "bio",
        "ignore_unmapped": false,
        "score_mode": "none",
        "boost": 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: perfect! This works as expected. But there is one problem. When the document is returned, ES is returning only "type" field in the response, ignoring other fields in the "mut" nested object. Lets say "id" is not present in the response. Is there any reason for this behaviour?